# How to Programmatically Enable Trust for VBA Project?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Getting the following error when trying to open a word document with macros to fill in the form fields:
**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Word\Security\AccessVBOM**

The user opening the word document does not have admin rights and the **AccessVBOM** flag is either not available or set to zero. I can set the flag for the HKCU programmatically but cannot change setting for **AccessVBOM** under HKLM.

Please advise how can we enable the trust for the VBA project programmatically.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25235214/6302131

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can, unless you change the setting in the registry. Without admin rights, not likely.

If you're on a corporate network that uses AD, you could use a GPO to set this - [Office 2003](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=BA8BC720-EDC2-479B-B115-5ABB70B3F490&displaylang=en&displaylang=en), [Office 2007](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=92D8519A-E143-4AEE-8F7A-E4BBAEBA13E7&displaylang=en), [Office 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=64B837B6-0AA0-4C07-BC34-BEC3990A7956&displaylang=en).