# Programatically bringing up Excel's "Trust Center Settings" dialog

Tags: vba, excel, vsto

I need users to click the "Trust access to the VBA project object model" so that an app I'm building can help them import code to the VBE.

I could display a messagebox or provide documentation telling them how to change setting (and warning about repercussions if they do). But that setting is still buried 5 clicks down in the Excel UI...in fact even I have trouble remembering where to find it.

So what I'd like to do is programmatically open that window for them.

I could probably use the notoriously fickle SendKeys method, but I wonder if there is a better way...

(I see that you can actually *set* access to the VBA project object model for users via a macro by using a VBS script to change the key's value when the target Office application is not running them as per [this MSDN article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cristib/archive/2012/02/29/vba-programmatically-enable-access-to-the-vba-object-model-using-macros.aspx) but I would much prefer that the user manually enables this option or elects not to).

Edit: VBA **or** VSTO solutions are fine, or anything else you can think of.

Comment: Alt, F, T, Down 9 times, Tab, T. SIMPLE ENOUGH!? Geez, memorize it already! Just kidding; unfortunately, I wouldn't know of any other way than with the flimsy SendKeys or a more sophisticated version of that, using AutoHotKey...

Comment: BTW I did test the Registry option and it doesn't seem to work (probably by design).  That seems to agree with the MSDN article you linked to (I hadn't read that last night).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This will bring up the dialog.

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("MacroSecurity")
```

Alternatively, this does the same thing:

```
Application.CommandBars.FindControl(Id:=3627).Execute
```

The user will need to check the box, it cannot be checked programmatically even using SendKeys.

**Extra Credit: Is it possible to change the registry key?**

There is also a registry key which you may be able to change using VBA.

[image]

I thought you might be able to use a subroutine like this to set the registry key to "allow access". However, as I tested this and it *does* change the registry key value, it doesn't seem to have any effect on my ability to access the VBOM:

- If my settings do not allow access, and I change the key value to 1, then I get a 1004 error.
- If my settings *do* allow access, and I change the key value to 0, sample code that manipulates the VBOM still works.
- If I change the registry key programmatically, it reverts to its previous state when re-starting the Excel Application.

It's possible I did something wrong, so I will leave this here on the off-chance that someone else can get it to work. I have used this sort of function to set custom registry keys for my own applications, i.e., to store the application's current version #, etc. but perhaps this part of the registry is simply locked down and can't be manipulated this way.

```
Const regKey As String = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\OFFICE\14.0\Excel\Security\AccessVBOM"
Sub AllowAccessToVBOM()
        With CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
            'write registry key
            .RegWrite regKey, "0", "REG_DWORD"
            MsgBox regKey & " : " & .regRead(regKey)
        End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Getting it to work would be a severe security issue IMO. Glad it's throwing - looks very very much like by-design behavior.

Comment: Agreed @Mat'sMug I don't think this should be allowed, so it's most likely not working by design. More of a "I was curious..." :D

Comment: TBH as I was reading through I kept thinking "OMG this can't be working, please don't tell me this is working!" - till that bullet about the 1004 error =)

Answer (score 0):

i was working on this and actually you CAN make it work with SendKeys and DoEvents. My following code works with 16.0 Spanish Version of Excel. Just define this with Ctrl + "m" and will run ok.

```
Option Explicit
#If VBA7 Then
    Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#Else
    Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
#End If

Sub VBATrust()
Dim x As Boolean, y As Boolean
Dim inicio, final

Application.OnKey "+{m}"

inicio = Now()
x = VBAIsTrusted

'If Application.LanguageSettings.LanguageID(msoLanguageIDUI) = 3082 _
'And Application.Version = "16.0" Then

    AppActivate (ThisWorkbook.Name & " - Excel")
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
    Application.SendKeys "%ao{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}%c", True
    Application.SendKeys "{UP}{UP}{UP}{UP}{UP}{UP}{UP}{UP}{UP}{UP}{UP}", True
    Application.SendKeys "{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}", True
    Application.SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB} ", True
    Application.SendKeys "~", True
    Application.SendKeys "{TAB}~", True

'End If

DoEvents
y = VBAIsTrusted
final = Now()

MsgBox inicio & " - Modelo de objetos VBA : " & x & vbNewLine & _
       final & " - Modelo de objetos VBA : " & y

End Sub

Public Function VBAIsTrusted() As Boolean
Dim a1 As Integer
On Error GoTo Label1
a1 = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Count
VBAIsTrusted = True
Exit Function
Label1:
VBAIsTrusted = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined a couple ideas here for this approach:

```
Function fTestGetAccessVBE()
    MsgBox fGetAccessVBE(True)
End Function

'_2023_03_20
Function fGetAccessVBE(Optional blnDialog As Boolean = False) As Boolean
Dim regKey As String
Dim blnAccess As Boolean

    regKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\OFFICE\" & _
    CStr(Application.Version) & "\Excel\Security\AccessVBOM"
    blnAccess = CBool(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").regRead(regKey))
    Select Case True
    Case blnAccess = True
    Case blnDialog = True
        MsgBox "Programmatic access to the VBA project is not trusted."
        Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("MacroSecurity")
        blnAccess = CBool(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").regRead(regKey))
    End Select
    fGetAccessVBE = blnAccess
    
End Function
```

This function looks in the registry to see if VBA access is enabled, so it doesn't require error trapping. It should also work in other versions of Office because the number isn't hard coded, I tested it on 16.0. It has an option to open the Macro Security dialog so the user can change the setting. Then it returns the final access status.