# How to duplicate a worksheet without duplicating its Worksheet Private sub code

Tags: excel, vba, copy

I'm trying to duplicate a worksheet with a macro, but when doing so, to private sub is duplicated as well, what I don't want to happen because it interferes afterward with another module macro. I have seen this post [Copy a worksheet without copying the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32016718/copy-a-worksheet-without-copying-the-code) and tried, but it doesn't work properly. Some ideas on how to do that?

```
Sub Export()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("CB").Select
MonthID = Range("N2").Value
YearID = Range("O2").Value
saldoID = Range("O18").Value

ActiveSheet.Unprotect
ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets("CB")

' Get the code/object name of the new sheet...
Dim Code As String
Code = ActiveSheet.CodeName

' Remove all lines from its code module...
With ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Code).CodeModule
    .DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines
End With
```

The last step (.DeleteLines 1, .CountOfLines) always causes an error: "Can't enter break mode at this moment" - Run time error 1004 Application defined or object defined error.

Why, what is wrong or missing??
Thanks

Comment: The [`CodeName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.codename) of the new sheet is not the same as the code in the sheet code module...

Comment: what can I do instead? I don't really get it

Comment: `Code = ActiveSheet.CodeName`.

Comment: thanksT that works
but at the .deleteLines 1, .countOfLines I have always a 1004 error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way:

1. copy sheet to new **workbook**
2. save new workbook as `.xlsx`
3. close new workbook
4. re-open new `.xlsx` workbook
5. copy the macro-free worksheet back to original workbook

The VBA code for this is simple; you could also include:

6. re-close the`.xlsx`
7. **kill** *(delete)* the `.xlsx` workbook