# Remove vba modules using python?

Tags: python, excel, winapi

It seems win32api should be able to do this given the answer [here](http://VBComponents.Remove) and [.

I would like to remove all modules from an excel workbook (.xls) using python

Comment: observed the same behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using the [VBComponents collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa443983(v=vs.60).aspx) available in the COM interface accessible with Python's `win23com.client` module. However, inside the particular workbook you need to first grant [programmatic access to the VBA object library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638344/programmatic-access-to-visual-basic-project-is-not-trusted-excel).

Also, you will need to conditionally set the type as this procedure cannot delete object modules including Sheets (`Type = 100`) and Workbooks (`Type = 100`). Only Standard Modules (`Type = 1`), Class Modules (`Type = 2`), UserForms (`Type= 3`), and other inserted components can be removed. Of course you can iterate through defined list of modules to remove. `Try/Except` statement is used to effectively close out the Excel.Application process whether script fails or not.

```
import win32com.client

# OPEN EXCEL APP AND WORKBOOK
xlApp = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xlwb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Path\\To\\Workbook.xlsm")

# ITERATE THROUGH EACH VB COMPONENT (CLASS MODULE, STANDARD MODULE, USER FORMS)
try:    
    for i in xlwb.VBProject.VBComponents:        
        xlmodule = xlwb.VBProject.VBComponents(i.Name)
        if xlmodule.Type in [1, 2, 3]:            
            xlwb.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove(xlmodule)

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

finally:    
    # CLOSE AND SAVE AND UNINITIALIZE APP
    xlwb.Close(True)
    xlApp.Quit

    xlApp = None
```

Comment: Very interesting. I will be testing to day and accept when it works - it appears to be exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Any luck in testing? Be sure to grant programmatic access in workbook.

Answer (score 1):

Actually simply reading in the file with [`xlrd`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd), copying with [`xlutils`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlutils), and spitting it out with [`xlwt`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt) will remove the VBA (and other stuff):

```
import xlrd, xlwt
from xlutils.copy import copy as xl_copy
rb = xlrd.open_workbook('/path/to/fin.xls')
wb = xl_copy(rb)
wb.save('/path/to/fou.xls')
```

Comment: *"will remove [...] other stuff"* may not be desirable. At the very least, it should be documented, what it is.

Comment: Good point, @IInspectable! I will do some research to find out what else is removed.

Comment: Please see this question for a discussion about what else is removed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723793/preserving-styles-using-pythons-xlrd-xlwt-and-xlutils-copy

Comment: @bernie could you include information about preserving cells formatting parameter (`formatting_info=True` when calling `open_workbook method`) in your response? I'm reffering to http://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html and your note in comment.