# Automatically display the IDE when a workbook is opened

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to automatically display the IDE when Excel is launched.

Is there a way to simulate a click on the "Visual Basic Editor" icon in the ribbon? I looked into `Application.CommandBars` but there's nothing about the Ribbon.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' Display Visual Basic Editor
End Sub
```

Comment: For the quick and dirty (assuming you don't mind ending up in Debug mode), `Stop` works.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Commandbars` object has an `ExecuteMso` method that allows you to "push" any Ribbon button, so:

```
Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("VisualBasic")
```

As noted by Comintern, the `Application` qualification is necessary when using this in a `Workbook_Open` event, otherwise you'll get an error 91.

To find the mso, go into the Quick Access toolbar's Ribbon menu, find what you want and hover:

[image]

Comment: +1 for not requiring programmatic access. Note that `CommandBars.ExecuteMso` needs to be qualified with `Application.`.

Comment: Thanks @Comintern. I didn't have to qualify it, but I'm generally a verbose coder (when not racing the SO clock), so I'll add that.

Comment: Weird.  It gives me an error 91 (Excel 2013 x32) when it isn't qualified.  I wonder if the Workbook isn't ready in time for the call if it's in `Workbook_Open()`.

Comment: @Comintern, you are oh-so-right about that. When I actually do the tedious work of stuffing it in Workbookj_Open, save it and re-open, it fails without the Application bit. Thanks!

Comment: @Doug Glancy, thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: It's not a function so you can drop those parentheses. That then gives you `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "VisualBasic"`. Right now they are just telling VBA to "evaluate this bit first", which you don't need.

Answer (score 3):

It would be

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ' Display Visual Basic Editor
    Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True 
End Sub
```

If you get Programmatic Access error:
[Programmatic Access To Visual Basic Project Is Not Trusted - Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638344/programmatic-access-to-visual-basic-project-is-not-trusted-excel)