# Open VBA window by clicking macro button in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am using excel and learning how to code in vba for macro buttons.

I was trying to create button and put a code so that when I double click on the button vba window gets open instead of using shortcut alt+f11.

Can anyone please provide any details if there is any code ? Thanks

Comment: could try giving `Application.SendKeys` ago

Comment: Can you please provide complete code for as I am beginner and can’t understand ? Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Can you explain the use case?

Comment: Insert a button and in the onclick event put `Application.SendKeys("%f11")` I think that would work, give it a try. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys

Comment: universal answer: if you're a total beginner, try using the recorder. Then examine the code.

Comment: Its just for my learning this came in to mind to practice as I have seen I can open files and exe using macros and the code is available easily. But couldn’t find any thing like this opening vba window using button double click.

Comment: #SlappedProgrammer %f11 is not working

Comment: @PatrickHonorez - the recorder won't show the activation of the VBE though..?

Comment: A button typically works with a single click, not a double click. And I think it would be far more useful to execute a part of your own code instead of trying to get it to open the VBA editor.

Comment: @CLR indeed. My bad. Not a universal answer :(

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Put this in the sheet object your button is on.

Comment: How to implement this for double click ?

Comment: It gives error program access to vba is not trusted how can O fix that ?

Comment: Now it gives compile error: user-defined type not defined. Also it opens in single click

Comment: This has to do with your vba trust settings. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638344/programmatic-access-to-visual-basic-project-is-not-trusted) should help you sort that out.

Comment: @user3102147 If it doesn't work, it will throw an error right away, opening the window automatically. This is due to the error, not the code. Have you added anything to the single click module of your code?

Comment: I have only copy pasted the code which you have mentioned and it gives compile error: User-defined type not defined

Comment: It is might be becuase of MsForms because when I type the code I don’t see any of these option as I am working on sheet in excel not on forms

Comment: If you open your vba window, click tools > References and check if your `Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library` is selected as it should be.