# Programmatic access to Office VBA project is denied

Tags: vba, ms-word, reference

I want to monitor my references.

But no matter what I use:

```
For Each objReference In VBE.ActiveVBProject.References
```

```
For Each objReference In ActiveDocument.VBProject.References
```

```
Set mytemplate = ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate
For Each objReference In mytemplate.VBProject.References
```

I get the error 6068

Programmatic access to Office VBA project is denied,
becuse the user has not set the "Trust access to the VBA project object model" check box.

But I cannot ask users to make changes in the Trust Center.

So my question is, can you give permission via VBA?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatic Access To Visual Basic Project Is Not Trusted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638344/programmatic-access-to-visual-basic-project-is-not-trusted)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give trusted access to the VBA project object model via code. Were that possible, virus/malware writers would have a field day.