# Parameter transmission from Excel into Macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

I am making a Macro in VBA (Excel 2016 32bit + Windows 10 Pro) that fires when ***Workbook.NewSheet*** event occurs.
This Macro must rename ***Sheet.CodeName*** property of every new sheet.

The problem is that when I run my Macro in breaking mode, step by step, it works perfectly.
But it can’t rename ***Sheet.CodeName*** property after VB Editor (VBE) is closed. Simply ***Sheet.CodeName*** property is empty, so Macro doesn’t know what sheet must have to renamed. If I open VBE and, doing nothing, close it again, Macro runs rightly. 
And next, this Macro works correctly with ***Workbook.Open*** and ***Workbook.SheetChange*** events. Only ***Workbook.NewSheet*** event gives a trouble.

Give me a suggest, please, if you know, how I can improve parameter transmit from Excel to my Macro behind closed VBE.

Hi!

Thank You for want to helping me!
The code is very easy.
The goal is - get properly value of sh_CodeName property in message window
when VBE is closed.

Current code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal sh As Object)
NewSheet sh
End Sub

Option Explicit
Sub NewSheet(ByVal sh As Object)
Dim sh_CodeName As String, sh_Name As String, i As Integer

sh_CodeName = sh.CodeName: sh_Name = sh.Name

MsgBox "Code Name - " & sh_CodeName & vbCrLf & "Name - " & sh_Name, vbOKOnly, "MESSAGE FROM WorkBook.NewSheet"

End Sub
```

Comment: Help us to help you;  **post your current code.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `sh.codename` is not available after adding a new sheet as long as one has not accessed the VBA project. Maybe someone else hase more on this.

This code works for me but has the disadvantage that you need to [trust access to the VBA project object model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638344/programmatic-access-to-visual-basic-project-is-not-trusted).

```
Sub NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim sh_CodeName As String, sh_Name As String, i As Integer


    sh_CodeName = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Sh.Name).Properties("_Codename")
    sh_Name = Sh.Name

    MsgBox "Code Name - " & sh_CodeName & vbCrLf & "Name - " & sh_Name, vbOKOnly, "MESSAGE FROM WorkBook.NewSheet"

End Sub
```

Even this simple macro will not give a codename when run with closed VBE

```
Sub TestAddIt()

Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    MsgBox sh.Name & " - " & sh.CodeName

End Sub
```

**PS**: Another workaround could be to open the VBE and close it again but you still need access to the VBA project

```
Sub TestAddIt()

Dim Sh As Worksheet

    Set Sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    With Application.VBE.MainWindow
        .WindowState = 1
        .Visible = True
        .Visible = False
    End With

    MsgBox Sh.Name & " - " & Sh.CodeName

End Sub
```

**Update**: This also worked  for me.

```
Sub TestAddIt()

Dim Sh As Worksheet

    Set Sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    ' Recompile the project
    Application.VBE.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=578).Execute

    MsgBox Sh.Name & " - " & Sh.CodeName

End Sub
```

Comment: Why I can't add the name of author of the answers? My posts published with out this string "Dear Storax!". My thanks to Storax!

Comment: Don't worry! Fine with me.

Comment: It is very interesting way. I shall try it out any later, must to do another job. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You help me with this statement.

```
sh_CodeName = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(Sh.Name).Properties("_Codename")
```

I modified it slightly (Sh.CodeName instead of Sh.Name). And added a delay.

```
Sub Check_NewSheet(ByVal sh As Object)
    Dim sh_CodeName As String, sh_Name As String, i As Integer

On Error Resume Next
    sh_CodeName = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(sh.CodeName).Properties("_Codename")
If Err.number > 0 Then
i = 0
Do While sh_CodeName = ""
    sh_CodeName = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(sh.CodeName).Properties("_Codename")
DoEvents
i = i + 1
Loop
End If
sh_Name = sh.Name

    MsgBox "Code Name - " & sh_CodeName & vbCrLf & "Name - " & sh_Name & vbCrLf & _
    "Attempts - " & i, vbOKOnly, "MESSAGE FROM WorkBook.NewSheet"

End Sub
```

It works pretty good now. It is quite well as an interim solution. 
But I still interested to find out an explanation what is wrong in the Excel to Macro communication. 
So, if you will find one, please, share it with me.

Comment: Possibly there is nothing wrong. Maybe that's just the way it is. As said it seems as long as you have not accessed the VBA project after you have added a sheet programmatically the codename is not available. Maybe a kind of re-complie is needed and that is done as soon as you access the VBA project. BUT I am guessing :-(

Comment: Updated my above solution with another approach which might save you the loop.