Copy Sheets to new WorkBook with modules
I have some code that is successfully pulling the required sheets into a new workbook and saving said workbook in same location as the source workbook.  However, I cant get the modules to copy over as well.  When I run this code, I get no errors, but the Modules dont copy over to new workbook either.  Please advise.
Dim path As String
Dim filename1 As String
filename1 = Worksheets("Instructions").Range("P1").Text & " Tech Eval"
path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"

Worksheets(Array("Narrative", "Summary Page", "Exceptions", "Offer Rating Sheet")).Copy

 With ActiveWorkbook
 .SaveAs Filename:=path & filename1, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
 End With

Dim strFolder As String, strTempFile As String
strFolder = ActiveWorkbook.path
If Len(strFolder) = 0 Then strFolder = CurDir
strFolder = strFolder & "\"
strTempFile = strFolder & "~tmpexport.bas"
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module2").Export strTempFile
Workbooks(filename1).VBProject.VBComponents.import strTempFile
Kill strTempFile

New code - Same error on same line. Run Time Error '1004': Programmatic access to Visual Basic Project is not trusted
Dim path As String
Dim filename1 As String
filename1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Instructions").Range("P1").Text & " Tech Eval"
path = ThisWorkbook.path & "\"

Dim tgWkb As Workbook
Set tgWkb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim strFolder As String, strTempFile As String
strFolder = ActiveWorkbook.path
If Len(strFolder) = 0 Then strFolder = CurDir
strFolder = strFolder & "\"
strTempFile = strFolder & "~tmpexport.bas"
tgWkb.VBProject.VBComponents("Module2").Export strTempFile

Worksheets(Array("Narrative", "Summary Page", "Exceptions", "Offer Rating Sheet")).Copy
With tgWkb
    .SaveAs Filename:=path & filename1, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
End With

'On Error Resume Next
'You have to refer to the right workbooks
Workbooks(filename1).VBProject.VBComponents.import strTempFile
Kill strTempFile


After removing the On Error Resume Next, what error do you get?

Would it be easier to create a copy of the existing file and then delete the unwanted sheets?  All modules will already exist then.

It looks like the issue is with the line ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module2").Export strTempFile.  It highlights that line but didnt give me an error message.

The posted answer hints that ActiveWorkbook and Workbooks(filename1) are the same workbook.

That's what the original code suggests as worksheets.copy will create a new workbook which becomes the active workbook because If you don't specify either Before or After, Microsoft Excel creates a new workbook that contains the copied Worksheet object. The newly created workbook holds the Application.ActiveWorkbook property ...

I changed the code to this as they are not the same workbook.  I am trying to get the modules from the original workbook to the new workbook. Same error.
tgWkb.VBProject.VBComponents("Module2").Export strTempFile
Workbooks(filename1).VBProject.VBComponents.import strTempFile.

Since you wrote "I can't get the modules to copy" which implies more than one, I wonder if you're trying to copy all modules or just some specified ones? If the former,
Darren Bartrup-Cook's idea seems perfect. Please let us know if that's an option.

If I could get this to work, I was going to do more than 1 module.  But I am now leaning towards 1 module with multiple subs in it.  It still doesnt work though.  I am going to edit my question with new code as I moved some things around hoping to get it to work , still same error on same line.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25638344/programmatic-access-to-visual-basic-project-is-not-trusted

Please confirm you made the reference to "Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility ..."

confirmed that I did this
