# How to enable Trust Access to the VBA Project using Registry and Ensure Excel Complies

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the setup I have.

ThisWorkbook will be the acting macro-enabled workbook with the code below.
ActiveWorkbook will be the workbook that ThisWorkbook is creating and adding Code Modules/References too.

*This is used to add references used in the ActiveWorkbook once it is created/opened later.*

```
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid GUID:="{420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228}", Major:=1, Minor:=0 'Microsoft Scripting Runtime
ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.References.AddFromGuid GUID:="{0002E157-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}", Major:=1, Minor:=0 'Microsoft VB for Applications Extensibility 5.3
```

Occasionally with the code above, Excel will throw a Application Defined Error. It breaks when it gets to these lines, as well as the code below when the above code is removed.

*This is used to Move Module1 from ThisWorkbook, into the ActiveWorkbook's CodeModule.*

```
Set SourceModule = Me.VBProject.VBComponents("Module1").CodeModule
Set DestinationModule = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveWorkbook.CodeName).CodeModule
```

My initial thought was it had something to do with references being incorrect however, I cant seem to get the error to clear at all.

EDIT: I have confirmed it is the VBProject throwing the error using `MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.VBProject.Name`

EDIT: I have discovered it was because of Developer Macro Settings. Currently I am using VBA to adjust a registry key for this setting, for some reason excel does not always recognize that it is changes so I have to manually change that setting. In conclusion, the error is still occuring however the question should be rephrased as "How to enable Trust Access to the VBA Project using Registry and Ensure Excel Complies"

Comment: When you say "... for some reason excel does not always recognize that...", you mean that it works only sometimes? Because from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25235214/5958842), it shouldn't work at all it seems.

Comment: To better phrase the issue. I am adjusting the registry values using VBA, however, excel must have some sort of background check to see if the user actually went into Macro Security Settings and pressed "Okay". Changing the Registry Values must not be enough to enable the things I want done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer Macro Settings was not enabled properly. Excel checks if the user has entered and physically pressed "Okay" in the Macro Security Options Menu. If settings are set via the Registry, It will not allow you to use VBOM unless you physically enter the options and press okay validating you have read and agree with the settings.

Comment: If you have answered your own question, please tick on the grey check mark to indicate to others that your answer is valid ... this also helps to keep the focus on the questions that do not have valid answers

Comment: @JohnM Unable too until 5 hours from now